# Not able to initialize the callback in my c code. Incompatible reference type causing the undefined behaviour

Tags: c, oop, pointers, callback, undefined-behavior

**Problem statement:** I'm initializing the callback `ops->cmd = pando_entry_cb` in my code but I get **undefined behaviour** because of **incompatible pointer type**. I knew the problem what it says but don't know what's the mistake in my code.

---

The Below provided code gives UB.I want to know how it can be corrected.

## UB Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct proc proc_t;
typedef struct proc_ops proc_ops_t;

proc_t *proc_new(proc_ops_t *ops);

struct proc_ops {
    //this is the callback
    int (*cmd)(proc_ops_t *ops, const void *tx_buf, unsigned tx_count, void *rx_buf, unsigned *rx_count);
    void *priv;
};

struct proc {
    proc_ops_t *ops;
};
//EDIT: Changed the return type
static int pando_entry_cb(proc_t *proc,  const void *tx_buf, unsigned tx_count,
               void *rx_buf, unsigned *rx_count) {

    printf("CB Entry point is called\n");
    printf("FROM_CB: D_proc: tx: %p, t_count: %d, rx :%p, r_count: %p\n", tx_buf,
      tx_count, rx_buf, rx_count);
    //EDIT
    return 1;
}

int proc_cmd(proc_t *proc, const void *tx_buf, unsigned tx_count,
               void *rx_buf, unsigned *rx_count) {
    int r;
    char s[256];

    printf("D_proc: tx: %p, t_count: %d, rx :%p, r_count: %p\n", tx_buf,
            tx_count, rx_buf, rx_count);
    r = proc->ops->cmd(proc->ops, tx_buf, tx_count, rx_buf, rx_count);
    if (r < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    //EDIT : Added the return type
    return 0;
}

proc_t *proc_new(proc_ops_t *ops) {
    proc_t *proc = malloc(sizeof(*proc));

    printf("Hello allocating the memory to proc struct\n");

    if (!proc) {
        printf("LOG_ERR :%s: malloc failed", __func__);
        return NULL;
    }

    memset(proc, 0, sizeof(*proc));

    //intitalize the struct callback and opaque pointer
    // problem is here where callback assignment from incompitable pointer type
    // Getting UB, here I know the pointer assignment isn't matching.
    // problem what I'm facing is this :  If a converted pointer is used to call a function
    // whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.
    ops->cmd = pando_entry_cb;  // <-- UB
    ops->priv = proc;

    return proc;
}

int main() {
  proc_t *proc;

  proc_ops_t *ops;
  // EDIT: Allocated the memory to ops
  proc_ops_t *ops = malloc(sizeof(*ops));
  memset(ops, 0, sizeof(*ops));
  proc = proc_new(ops);
  if (!proc) {
      return -1;
  }
  //Here I typecasted to void * to match the signature of function.
  proc_cmd(proc, (void*)8, 4, 0, 0);

  return 0;
}
```

### Want my expected output would look like below:

```
Hello allocating the memory to proc struct
D_proc: tx: 0x8, t_count: 4, rx :(nil), r_count: (nil)
CB Entry point is called
FROM_CB: D_proc: tx: 0x8, t_count: 4, rx :(nil), r_count: (nil)
```

Would be great I someone points me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

- I changed the return type of function pointer and the function which I initialise to identical type as int.
- Allocated the memory to the object which I missed.
- Added the return type to my function `int proc_cmd()`

Still, I get UB.

Appreciate for the help.

Comment: Well, don't try to assign pointers to incompatible types? Also, `proc_cmd` causes UB by not returning anything if `r >= 0`.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer Unfortunately there are a number of problems with this code, incompatible type function pointer being the lesser one. It's also not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve with such constructs, but I have a slight suspicion you're overcomplicating things for yourself.

Comment: @JohnLM, in my system, that callback entry is kind of entry to registering the device. Now, I've new serial device need to connect to the main machine, in that case, I need to just change the entry to the callback it will connect to my device. I'm in a situation where I need to use that callback as the toggle or some kind of enable/disable mechanism.  That's where I simplified the code in order to get help from stack overflow and this is my core issue I'm trying to use it as `pando_entry_cb`, but it never initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare the data type of `cmd` with the function you're trying to assign to it

```
int (*cmd)(proc_ops_t *ops, const void *tx_buf, unsigned tx_count, void *rx_buf, unsigned *rx_count);
static void pando_entry_cb(proc_t *proc,  const void *tx_buf, unsigned tx_count, void *rx_buf, unsigned *rx_count)
```

The return types differ as does the type for the first parameter. Your code expects the function to return something, so you should definitely make it return an `int`, even if that is always `0`.

And then in `proc_cmd` it only returns something if `r` is negative. Again you should have it return `0` or maybe the actual value of `r` if that's applicable.

Also you pass in an unassigned value into `proc_new` as `ops` isn't allocated at any point in the code that I can see.

And finally, when you create your `proc_t` you don't populate it's copy of `ops` so when you come to use it later, it's not set. You want to add in this line to the end of `proc_new` before you return.

```
proc->ops=ops;
```

Comment: Thanks for pinpointing the confliction return types, I have added the return type to my `proc_cmd()` function and changed the return type as int `pando_entry_cb()` that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer see the edit I just made about how you're not allocating any memory to `ops` before you use it.

Comment: I just edited my code from the above suggestion. Where I didn't allocate the memory to object ops. But I just added the suggestion in my code, still, I get the problem. Is it something I'm missing here?

Comment: I've spotted another problem which I've updated my answer with.

Comment: It's also not helpful to update your question with corrections given in answers as future visitors won't see the problems the answer is fixing

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. I 'll not change the question. I'll keep as it's so that other visitors can able to see the problem.

Comment: @JohnLM, your correct the `pando_entry_cb()` is never called. Even though I allocated the memory to all objects so that it won't point to illegal memory. still seems, I m missing something. Appreciate for your comments.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer I've tested all of the corrections and get your expected output so I'm not sure which part you've missed? I've made the last problem a bit more explicit just in case it wasn't clear too.

Comment: +1 @ChrisTurner, great. I found the mistake what I was doing.  You're true I didn't populate the copy of `ops`. Amazing, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried your code, but I know that a function pointer's return type must match the return type of the function it points to. E.g. `void (*func)()` can point to any function returning a void, but not to functions returning int. For that matter, you would need `int (*func)()` or `int (*func)(<list of arguments>)`. The function pointer type without list of arguments is independent of the number, and type of arguments of the function it points to but the one with arguments must match (thanks to @John Bollinger for pointing that out. See comments.). Beware that since the function pointer doesn't carry information about the parameters, the arguments are default-promoted.

I might also mention that C++ (by default) treats using a function pointer without parameter list to point to a function with parameters as an error. While the question is about C I find it useful to be aware of cases which makes C not a subset of C++.

Comment: Function pointer types ***that do not specify a parameter-type-list*** (as you present) are compatible with pointers to any function that returns the specified type.  Function pointer types that do specify a parameter-type-list are compatible only with pointers to functions whose return type *and* parameter types match.  Moreover, in the former case, you still must pass arguments of the correct types when you call the function, and you'll need to cast the pointer if you want to avoid the default argument promotions being applied. But most of that is moot, as the OP's case is the latter one.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this distiction between specified and non-specified lists. Thank you, I'll improve my answer.